# ColorMatrixFilter in Flash - add color, leave black

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, colormatrixfilter

I have a MovieClip - for example a character's face. It has a black border and a brown fill (skin). I need to change the skin's color.
I see 2 ways to go at it:

1. Use ColorTransform. But I need to have the skin in a separate MovieClip, so that I can change the skin's color alone, not the borders. It's kind of complicated. If i have some other elements, like semi transpatent shadows (they will stay brown).
2. Use something else (maybe ColorMatrixFilter)?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link. It answers you question pretty thoroughly:

[Changing fill color of MovieClip Actionscript 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796671/changing-fill-color-of-movieclip-actionscript-3)

To sum it up; it looks like your first method would be the best route to take.