# Change lines thickness/color for Sprite/MovieClip in ActionScript?

Tags: flash

I want to be able to change lines thickness/color for sprites/movieclips created in Flash CS in ActionScript code. Is it possible to achieve this kind of functionality?

Best Regards, Aleksey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot change the existing vectors in code. The technical term for what you're asking about is "stroke"; if you search that term then you can find information like this:

[Changing fill color of MovieClip Actionscript 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796671/changing-fill-color-of-movieclip-actionscript-3)

Answer (score 0):

You may, alternatively, draw simple objects with the `flash.display.graphics` api. Its not appropriate for complex objects - but great for simple forms, that you then have total control over.

```
var obj:Shape = new Shape();
with(obj){
   graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00,.2);
   graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,200);
   graphics.endFill();
}
```

This depends very much on the shape you wish to manipulate.