# ActionScript 3 color transform changes border only

Tags: actionscript-3, colortransform

I would like to know why does AS3 colorTransform only transforms the border of a shape?

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796671/changing-fill-color-of-movieclip-actionscript-3) is posted however I do not think that such a massive workaround needs to be done in order to do so.

I have something like:

```
var sh:Shape = new Shape();
sh.graphics.lineStyle(4, 0x000000);
sh.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFF00);
sh.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
sh.graphics.endFill();
addChild(sh);
```

Ye I know we can use **`with(sh.graphics) do`** here, however if I make a color transform like:

```
sh.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(1, 1, 1, 1, red_offset, green_ofs, b_off, 0);
```

Only the border of a shape is transformed.
I've tried to redraw on everyframe the object with different fill but it's an overkill in performance, about 10 3d planes were performance killers.

I can only think of that because `beginFill()` does not use a pen set by `lineStyle()` and that may be causing the problem, however I would really like to know the problem as I need my uber-super-semi3d-spinner to spin while changing colors and not his borders! :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why ColorTransform affects only line color (seems just design decision), but [ColorMatrixFilter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/ColorMatrixFilter.html) will transform entire shape (tested). Don't be afraid of it - it's quite simple. First four columns of matrix are multipliers (1.0 is 100%) and fifth column is added to result.

```
        var sht:Shape = new Shape();
        sht.graphics.lineStyle(4, 0x7F7FFF);
        sht.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
        sht.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
        sht.graphics.endFill();
        sht.x = 300;
        sht.y = 100;
        sht.filters = [ new ColorMatrixFilter(
            [   0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                0.0, 0.0, 0.7, 0.0, 0.0,
                0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0
            ])];
        addChild(sht);
```

Comment: Big thanks to you! Will try as soon as I will can. By the way what's the point of ColorTransform if ColorMatrixFilter provides much more power?

Comment: ColorTransform is simpler and should be faster - it's one vector multiplication or four scalar ones, and ColorMatrixFilter is four vector muls and one addition.